Dataframes come up empty after parsing Excel files
I am trying to write a python script with a gui that takes in two excel files that each contain an inventory of goods.
The column A will contain all the style numbers. The column B  will contain information about the styles. The column C will  contain all the number of styles currently in inventory.
The first excel file will have some cells in column A Highlighted in a color. The second file will not.
Some of these highlighted cells will have the same values in column A of the second excel file. The script will go into the second excel file and highlight these values in the same color.
Some cells will be highlighted in the first excel file, however, the values in those cells will not be found in the second excel file. the script will also go into the second excel file and create a new column with these values in separate rows, named "Sold Out" in column D.
The following is the script:
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import os

def highlight_matching_styles(file1_path, file2_path):
    # Read Excel files into pandas DataFrames
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file1_path)
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file2_path)

    # Get styles highlighted in the first Excel file
    highlighted_styles = set(df1.iloc[:, 0][df1.iloc[:, 0].notna()])

    # Highlight matching styles in the second Excel file
    for style in highlighted_styles:
        if style in df2.iloc[:, 0].values:
            style_index = df2[df2.iloc[:, 0] == style].index[0]
            style_cell = f"A{style_index + 1}"
            highlight_cell(style_cell)

    # Identify sold-out styles in the second Excel file
    sold_out_styles = highlighted_styles - set(df2.iloc[:, 0][df2.iloc[:, 0].notna()])
    if sold_out_styles:
        # Add a new column named "Sold Out" in the second Excel file
        df2["Sold Out"] = ""
        # Write sold-out styles to the "Sold Out" column
        for idx, style in enumerate(sold_out_styles, start=len(df2) + 1):
            df2.at[idx, "Sold Out"] = style

    # Save the modified DataFrame to a new Excel file with "_modified" appended to the file name
    output_file_path = os.path.splitext(file2_path)[0] + "_modified.xlsx"
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine="openpyxl") as writer:
        df2.to_excel(writer, index=False)

    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Styles highlighted and sold-out styles added successfully!")
    return output_file_path

def highlight_cell(cell):
    cell_format = PatternFill(start_color="FFFF00", end_color="FFFF00", fill_type="solid")
    ws[cell].fill = cell_format

def select_files():
    file1_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select the first Excel file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    file2_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select the second Excel file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    if file1_path and file2_path:
        try:
            output_file_path = highlight_matching_styles(file1_path, file2_path)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", f"Modified file saved at:\n{output_file_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please select both Excel files.")

# Create the GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Inventory Highlighter")

# Create and position widgets
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

btn_select_files = tk.Button(frame, text="Select Excel Files", command=select_files)
btn_select_files.pack()

# Run the application
root.mainloop()


I keep getting an error message stating that "single positional is out-of-bounds" after i select the two excel files, no matter how much I try to debug. The dataframes keep coming up empty.
The following is an example of the first excel file:
excel file
The following is an example of the second excel file:
second excel
I tried debugging and narrowed it down to the dataframes coming up empty after the script parses each excel file

I get: name 'ws' is not defined.
